# Menu disappears when device width is smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a menu but I have a problem with my `JavaScript`.

I messed up the JavaScript file, but it works in general. The thing is that when you load the page and your with is less than 858px and then you click in one of the items of the menu, if then you make your width larger the menu disappears. So I want to not disappear it.

**JavaScript, HTML and CSS:**

```js
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 858px)");

// Check if the media query is true
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  // function that hides the menu when a "ul li a" is clicked, then, if you click it again, it recovers its form
  function hide() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";

    // to do an autoclick to class "checkbtn"
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkbtn")[0].click();
  }

  // function that shows the menu when you click the hamburguer (fas fa-bars)
  function show() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "inherit";
  }
} else {
  function hide() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "inherit";
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkbtn")[0].click();
  }

  function show() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "inherit";
  }
}
// Initial check
handleTabletChange(mediaQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>test</title>

    <!-- (fonts.google.com) -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <script src="./main.js"></script>

    <!-- material design icons -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- hamburger menu -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

    <style>
      /* menu styling */
      nav {
        background: linear-gradient(
          90deg,
          rgba(255, 136, 75, 1) 0%,
          rgba(254, 72, 64, 1) 100%
        );
        height: 55px;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
      }

      label.logo {
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 55px;
        padding: 0 100px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      label.logo a {
        color: white;
      }

      label.logo a:hover {
        box-shadow: none;
        background: none;
      }

      nav ul {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border-radius: 0;
      }

      nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 55px;
        margin: 0 5px;
      }

      nav ul li a {
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 13px;
      }
      nav ul li a:hover {
        background-color: #2c3e50;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .checkbtn {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
        float: right;
        line-height: 55px;
        margin-right: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
      }

      #check {
        display: none;
      }

      /* menu media queries */
      @media (max-width: 952px) {
        label.logo {
          font-size: 25px;
          padding-left: 50px;
        }

        nav ul li a {
          font-size: 16px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 858px) {
        .checkbtn {
          display: block;
        }

        ul {
          position: fixed;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100vh;
          background: #2c3e50;
          top: 55px;
          left: -100%;
          text-align: center;
          transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        nav ul li {
          display: block;
          margin: 50px 0;
          line-height: 30px;
        }

        nav ul li a {
          font-size: 17px;
        }

        nav ul li a:hover {
          background: linear-gradient(
            90deg,
            rgba(255, 136, 75, 1) 0%,
            rgba(254, 72, 64, 1) 100%
          );
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 25px rgb(254, 72, 64);
        }

        #check:checked ~ ul {
          left: 0;
        }
      }
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: all 0.6s;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #2c3e50;
        color: white !important;
        font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
      }

      .cssAnimation:hover {
        transform: translateY(10px) !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <!-- menu -->
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn"
        ><i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="show()"></i
      ></label>
      <label class="logo"><a href="#body">Name</a></label>
      <ul id="hidden">
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="hide()">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="hide()">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="hide()">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="hide()">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's okay if you improve the question i've asked but in this case i think to run code snippet isn't very useful, it's better to copy the code into an html file and also into a javascript file, so you can see the issue i'm having, all opened in a new tab on your favourite browser to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "hide()" makes the navigation disappear. For example, you said in the navigation that if you click on the list element, the navigation should disappear. If you remove the "display: none" everything should work as you wanted it to.

```
      function hide() {
        document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";
    
        // to do an autoclick to class "checkbtn"
        document.getElementsByClassName("checkbtn")[0].click();
      }
```

Try it this way:

```js
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 858px)");

// Check if the media query is true
if (mediaQuery.matches) {
  // function that hides the menu when a "ul li a" is clicked, then, if you click it again, it recovers its form
  function hide() {
    // to do an autoclick to class "checkbtn"
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkbtn")[0].click();
  }

  // function that shows the menu when you click the hamburguer (fas fa-bars)
  function show() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "inherit";
  }
} else {
  function hide() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "inherit";
    document.getElementsByClassName("checkbtn")[0].click();
  }

  function show() {
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "inherit";
  }
}
// Initial check
handleTabletChange(mediaQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>test</title>

    <!-- (fonts.google.com) -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- material design icons -->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <!-- hamburger menu -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

    <style>
      /* menu styling */
      nav {
        background: linear-gradient(
          90deg,
          rgba(255, 136, 75, 1) 0%,
          rgba(254, 72, 64, 1) 100%
        );
        height: 55px;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
      }

      label.logo {
        color: white;
        font-size: 25px;
        line-height: 55px;
        padding: 0 100px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      label.logo a {
        color: white;
      }

      label.logo a:hover {
        box-shadow: none;
        background: none;
      }

      nav ul {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 20px;
        border-radius: 0;
      }

      nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 55px;
        margin: 0 5px;
      }

      nav ul li a {
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 7px 13px;
      }
      nav ul li a:hover {
        background-color: #2c3e50;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }

      .checkbtn {
        font-size: 30px;
        color: white;
        float: right;
        line-height: 55px;
        margin-right: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
      }

      #check {
        display: none;
      }

      /* menu media queries */
      @media (max-width: 952px) {
        label.logo {
          font-size: 25px;
          padding-left: 50px;
        }

        nav ul li a {
          font-size: 16px;
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 858px) {
        .checkbtn {
          display: block;
        }

        ul {
          position: fixed;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100vh;
          background: #2c3e50;
          top: 55px;
          left: -100%;
          text-align: center;
          transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        nav ul li {
          display: block;
          margin: 50px 0;
          line-height: 30px;
        }

        nav ul li a {
          font-size: 17px;
        }

        nav ul li a:hover {
          background: linear-gradient(
            90deg,
            rgba(255, 136, 75, 1) 0%,
            rgba(254, 72, 64, 1) 100%
          );
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 25px rgb(254, 72, 64);
        }

        #check:checked ~ ul {
          left: 0;
        }
      }
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: all 0.6s;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #2c3e50;
        color: white !important;
        font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
      }

      .cssAnimation:hover {
        transform: translateY(10px) !important;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <!-- menu -->
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn"
        ><i class="fas fa-bars" onclick="show()"></i
      ></label>
      <label class="logo"><a href="#body">Name</a></label>
      <ul id="hidden">
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="hide()">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="hide()">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="hide()">Test</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" onclick="hide()">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Happy Coding!**

Comment: so you just removed this line and now it works?? ```document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";```

Comment: and how can i reduce the lines of my JavaScript code? like optimize it in some way to make it faster/cleaner

Comment: Yes you had to remove the `document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "none";`

Comment: Actually, the code is very good. I have not seen what could be done better.